# What is the unit for memory usage in VTK?

Tags: vtk, paraview

I wonder what is the unit for reporting a memory usage returned by `vtkPVMemoryUseInformation.GetProcMemoryUse` ([reference](https://kitware.github.io/paraview-docs/nightly/cxx/classvtkPVMemoryUseInformation.html#a58e57d65a9e5ffadc2396d5fcf0ee03b))? Is it a bit, byte, kilobyte? Where can I find this in the documentation?

---

### Update 1

I'm calling the mentioned function from a Python-script with `servermanager.vtkPVMemoryUseInformation().GetProcMemoryUse(<index>)`. We don't have `size_t` in Python, right? The main question is **how can I convert the value into a human-readable value like MB or GB** returned by a function call?

Comment: the reference point that it is in `size_t`, see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t   std::size_t is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator......

Comment: @Luuk thank you, I've updated the question. I use Python, does it change the type or value of the function? But the main question is how to convert this value to bytes, kilobytes?

Comment: @Luuk, according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof, it returns a number in bytes. So, is it correct that `servermanager.vtkPVMemoryUseInformation().GetProcMemoryUse(<index>)` also returns bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method internally uses vtksys::SystemInformation, which returns system RAM used in units of KiB.

https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Utilities/KWSys/vtksys/SystemInformation.hxx.in

The doc should be improved here.